# Adobe Acrobat "Save as Text" Parser

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, pdfbox, acrobat

I'm trying to convert PDFs to text for parsing, and have run into issues with complex-structured PDFs, such as the following sample student aid report:
[image: Sample Document] You can assume my PDFs are text encoded.

Parsing with Apache Tika/PDFBox and Norconex Importer (which relies on the Apache libraries) returns the following:

```
1. Last Name 2. First Name 3. Middle Initial
4. Mailing Address
5. City 6. State Abbreviation 7. ZIP Code
8. Social Security Number 9. Date of Birth 10. Your telephone number
11. Driver's License Number
12. Driver's License State Abbreviation
13. Student's E-mail Address
...[header/footer text]...
SMITH JOHN J
Processed: 04/22/2019
742 EVERGREEN TERRACE
SPRINGFIELD
XXX-XX-4444
JOHNSMITH@HOTMAIL.COM
```

which is difficult for parsing as paired keys and values are separated by other keys/values, or junk text. However, using Adobe Acrobat's Save as Text option, I get the following:

```
1.Last Name
SMITH
16-character answer box for question 1
2.First Name
JOHN
12-character answer box for question 2
3.Middle Initial
J
1-character answer box for question 3 
4.Mailing Address
742 EVERGREEN TERRACE
35-character answer box for question 4 
5.City
SPRINGFIELD
16-character answer box for question 5
```

I'm guessing that Adobe Acrobat has an implicit dictionary structure for mapping the fields to the answer boxes, but are there any document reading libraries that preserve this structure? Or is there a way to configure the Apache or Norconex libraries to handle this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: When parsing with a PDFBox `PDFTextStripper` directly, try applying `setSortByPosition(true)`. This will at least give you a fairly accurate line-by-line output.

Comment: In the case of Save as Text, Acrobat attempts to output the text in reading order. It's not actually mapping anything via that path. However, if your PDF is an actual fillable form, you can use PDFBox to get the field values without having to infer the field name based on the text position. Just iterate through the fields and get the name/value pairs.